# MVC4 Trying to get the security model to work with my Environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I hope someone will be able to put me on the right track, been trying to resolve this now for hours.
I am currently in the process of redeveloping a web application and I would like to use the MVC4 attributes for managing access to the various parts of the application.
The issue I am having is that the Authentication & Permissions are all handled by middle-ware applications that the web app has to interface with.

I was wondering if even with this restriction would I be able to use the security attributes & letting the web app know that the user is Authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to use existing Authorize attribute. All you have to do is write a custom [`Membership`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`Role`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) providers that will use your existing services instead of relying on the default SQL database.

If you don't want to go through all this hassle you could also write a custom authorization attribute (deriving from `AuthorizeAttribute`) and inside the `AuthorizeCore` method call your service to check whether the current user has the desired roles.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. Not only is it possible, but also it's pretty easy. And if you can think of ASP.NET Roles as "activities", then you don't need to derive anything; everything you need is built in.

These examples assume `securityService` is the service that communicates with your middle-ware applications, and has two methods, `GetUser` and `GetUserRoles`:

**Your Login action method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

    var user = securityService.GetUser(model.Username, model.Password);
    if (user == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or password are incorrect.");
        return View();
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, model.Remember);
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

**In your Global.asax.cs**

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string username = User.Identity.Name;
        string[] roles = securityService.GetUserRoles(username);
        IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        Context.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles);
    }
}
```

That's it. `Login` handles the authentication (when the user logs in), while `Application_AuthenticateRequest` handles the authorization (on every request). You then proceed to decorate your action methods with `Authorize(Roles = "XYZ")` making sure "XYZ" matches what comes back from your `GetUserRoles` method.